# Where does the soap go once open?

Tags: hotels

This is the bathroom of my hotel (the other side of the sink is the same):

[image]

Where is the soap supposed to be placed, once it is opened and used? (I use the plastic tray, but it is all flat, slippery - does not quite look like the right place)

Comment: That looks like a triumph of style over substance to me - designed by someone who didn’t consider the practicalities! I don’t think there’s a ‘right’ answer, the plastic tray does seem like the intended place but it’s your room - put the used soap wherever you like :-)

Comment: Based on the title I came here expecting a question on what do hotels do with all those soap bars that have only been used once :D

Comment: @PeterM [that question now exists](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/131164/18491)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst there isn't a right answer it looks like the soap is intended to go on the plastic tray and the shampoo/conditioner bottles to be taken off the try and onto the surface around the sink.

The only reason I would do that is not to have slippery soap on the whole surface andake it slipper but just keep it on the plastic tray.

Anyway that's my opinion but it's totally up to you!